# I have two dataframes and I need to compare them to each other and calculate a measure

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes in python and need to do a measure based on date condition

DF1 has a column named VALUE that I need to divide based on column EXCHANGE from DF2

```
DF1: 

   MONTH     VALUE
2021-01-01    50
2021-01-01    75
2021-01-01    100
2021-03-01    150
2021-04-01    100
2021-03-01    150
2021-03-01    150 

DF2: 
    MONTH     EXCHANGE
2021-01-01     4
2021-02-01     4
2021-03-01     2
2021-04-01     10

I NEED TO TRANSFORM THE DF1 INTO:

   MONTH               VALUE
2021-01-01              12.5 --> 50/4
2021-01-01              18.75 --> 75 (PREVIOUS VALUE) / 4 (EXCHANGE VALUE)
2021-01-01              25
2021-03-01              75
2021-04-01              10   --> 100/10                     
2021-03-01              75
2021-03-01              75
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you explain how you are getting 12,5 and 18,75 from these two dataframes. 
like what are 12,5 and 18,75

Comment: also is 12,5 a tuple or are you using the ',' for float number?

Comment: Thank you for the observations, I added the explication from where the numbers come. And I replaced the ',' for '.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about retaining the original order of `DF1` then

```
result = DF1.set_index('MONTH')['VALUE'].div(DF2.set_index('MONTH')['EXCHANGE']).dropna().to_frame('VALUE')

            VALUE
MONTH            
2021-01-01  12.50
2021-01-01  18.75
2021-01-01  25.00
2021-03-01  75.00
2021-03-01  75.00
2021-03-01  75.00
2021-04-01  10.00
```

Otherwise, [saad_saeed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70523907/16746253) should work fine, optionally dropping the `EXCHANGE` column.

```
result = DF1.merge(DF2, how='left', on='MONTH')
result['VALUE'] = result['VALUE'].div(result['EXCHANGE'])

        MONTH  VALUE  EXCHANGE
0  2021-01-01  12.50         4
1  2021-01-01  18.75         4
2  2021-01-01  25.00         4
3  2021-03-01  75.00         2
4  2021-04-01  10.00        10
5  2021-03-01  75.00         2
6  2021-03-01  75.00         2
```

...or this one liner which also retains the original order

```
DF1['VALUE'] = DF1.merge(DF2, how='left', on='MONTH').apply(lambda x: x['VALUE'] / x['EXCHANGE'], axis=1)

        MONTH  VALUE
0  2021-01-01  12.50
1  2021-01-01  18.75
2  2021-01-01  25.00
3  2021-03-01  75.00
4  2021-04-01  10.00
5  2021-03-01  75.00
6  2021-03-01  75.00
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pandas allows you to divide columns by columns. Assuming your `DF1` and `DF2` have the same length, you could create a new column called `'values'`:

```
DF1['values'] = DF1['VALUE']/DF2['EXCHANGE']

Output

DF1: 

   MONTH      VALUE    values
2021-01-01    50       12,5
2021-01-01    75       18, 75
2021-01-01    100      25
2021-03-01    150      75
2021-04-01    100      ...
2021-03-01    150      ...
2021-03-01    150      ...
```

Then, you could drop the initial `VALUE` column:

```
DF1 = DF1.drop('VALUE', 1)

Output:

   MONTH               values
2021-01-01              12.5 --> 50/4
2021-01-01              18.75 --> 75 (PREVIOUS VALUE) / 4 (EXCHANGE VALUE)
2021-01-01              25
2021-03-01              75
2021-04-01              10                        
2021-03-01              75
2021-03-01              75
```

**Edit**:

For the solution asked in the comments to this answer. I would suggest creating a new empty `EXCHANGE` column in `DF1`.

```
DF1['EXCHANGE'] = ""


Output:
            MONTH      VALUE    EXCHANGE
            2021-01-01    50       
            2021-01-01    75       
            2021-01-01    100      
            2021-03-01    150      
            2021-04-01    100      
            2021-03-01    150      
            2021-03-01    150
```

And then use the loc method to add values to the existing column-based on the desired date-time condition.

```
DF1.loc[df1['MONTH'] == '2021-01-01', 'EXCHANGE'] = 4
DF1.loc[df1['MONTH'] == '2021-04-01', 'EXCHANGE'] = 10

Output:
        MONTH      VALUE    EXCHANGE
        2021-01-01    50       4
        2021-01-01    75       4
        2021-01-01    100      4
        2021-03-01    150      ?
        2021-04-01    100      10
        2021-03-01    150      ?
        2021-03-01    150      ?
```

Once you have done that, you can apply the above procedure, just using the two DF1 columns this time. Note: the `'?'` in the `DF1 EXCHANGE` column is there since I am not sure what value you want for the third month in the month column.

Comment: Mh, I am still not sure I understand what you mean. If the value you want to divide for is stored in the 'EXCHANGE' column, the solution I provided should work regardless. Also, are you using EU or US date format?

Comment: The date format is yyyy-mm-dd. I need to compare the value in df1 and check based on df2, with the respective date as key, what number I need to divide. For example, for a value in df1 in the date 2021-01-01, I need to divide value by 4. For a value in df1 in the date 2021-04-01, I need to divide by 10.

Comment: @LucasLino  keep in mind that the order of the values will be respected when you divide a column by a column (i.e., the value in row 1 in DF1 will be divided by the exchange value in row 1 in DF2 and so on)

Comment: I see what you mean. You may want to specify this then in your question. Also, what object type are the dates in the month column? are they strings?

Comment: They are strings. I know it's not the correct but in this case I only need to compare if is equal and both are in the same format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240544/discussion-between-corvusmidnight-and-lucas-lino).

Comment: Corvus, thank you for your time! Happy new year and thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid going into loops and if-else. You can use "Merge" to combine the two DataFrames based on column values and divide as usual:

```
DF1 = DF1.merge(DF2, on=['MONTH'])
```

Next divide VALUE by EXCHANGE:

```
DF1['VALUE'] = DF1['VALUE'].div(DF1['EXCHANGE'])
```

Finally drop EXCHANGE column from DF1:

```
DF1.drop(['EXCHANGE'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(DF1)
```

Final Output:

```
MONTH  VALUE
1/1/2021  12.50
1/1/2021  18.75
1/1/2021  25.00
3/1/2021  75.00
3/1/2021  75.00
3/1/2021  75.00
4/1/2021  10.00
```